# Laravel composer update error: Nothing to install or update

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

When I run composer update, I get the following error:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Nothing to install or update
>   Generating autoload files
>   Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
>   php artisan optimize
>     [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Class 'Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider' not found
>   Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with err
>   or code 255

I put this code on the app.php file

> Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider::class,

and in the composer.json I also put this

> "laravel/cashier": "~6.0"

like in the laravel doc

[stack errot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eWLx.png)

Answer (score 6):

Remove the

```
Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider::class,
```

from `app.php`.
It needs to be added *after* installing the package.

Also, instead of `composer update`, try `composer require` without changing the `composer.json` file.

```
composer require laravel/cashier
```

Comment: ok but when  i removed this Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider::class
it told me there is nothing to install or update

Comment: try doing `composer require` instead of changing the `composer.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add anything in `composer.json` file or `app.php`.

Just follow the documentation given in Laravel website for [Laravel Cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#installation), (select the laravel version which you are using in your project).

Run the commands in following order:

```
//install the package and add it in composer file
 composer require laravel/cashier

//add your cashier class in 'providers' array in app.php
 Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider::class,

//add alias in 'aliases' array in app.php
'Cashier' => Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider::class,

//will add several columns to users table & create a new subscriptions table
 php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the php version in cmd useing `php -v`
2. if php version is < 7.0 then install latest version of php.
3. Uninstall the old verion Xampp
4. Install latest version of Xampp to upgrade php.

Comment: Why are you even mentioning Xampp?